# Manipulating visibility of a Material UI/React Badge component based on content in the badgeContent

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Badge component from Material UI but it displays even when it's empty. Kind of silly they wouldn't build that functionality out of the box. Why would anyone want an empty badge? Anyhow, I have it wired up to my APIs to read from the data, but as I said, I would like the entire Badge (icon and bubble) to `display=none` when `name.warningsCount == 0` and `name.problemsCount = 0`. I'm having a hard time getting this done.

Here is the snippet of that code:

```
<Badge
    className="warning-badge"
    badgeContent={name.warningsCount > 0 && name.warningsCount}>
    <AlertWarning />
</Badge>
<Badge
    className="problems-badge"
    badgeContent={name.problemsCount > 0 && name.problemsCount}>
    <AlertWarning />
</Badge>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could also just render the badge when `name.warningsCount` is not empty:

```js
{name.warningsCount > 0 && (
    <Badge
        className="warning-badge"
        badgeContent={name.warningsCount}
    >
        <AlertWarning />
    </Badge>
)}
```

No need to hide elements that shouldn't be rendered in the first place.

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I get back in my Mac. It makes lots of sense. It's been a long day. Thanks. I'll check back later tonight

Comment: That makes sense if your children elements are dependant of the badge. However, I'm encountering the same problem and I have children that should always be displayed, I want only the badge to disappear, I'm struggling to do this as well.

Comment: @GeoffreyHug Why don't you just exclude them from the conditional rendering clause then? Of course, there is no need to include all your children into the condition.

Comment: I guess I could just do something like `condition ? <Badge>children</Badge> : children`.

Comment: @GeoffreyHug Yes that‘s absolutely possible.

Answer (score 5):

Latest Material UI version will not show a badge by default if the value is zero. This is because of a new `showZero` property which defaults to `false`. Then previous versions included the `invisible` property where you could put something like `invisible={name.WargningsCount === 0}`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize `showZero` was even a thing until I started using `get(myObject, 'property', '0')` (lodash) which will cause a _string_ of 0 instead of an integer of 0.